# nodejs events - EventEmitter - understanding class instances

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, eventemitter

I am instantiating an event emitter and noticed that both of these lines seem to work fine.

Could anyone clarify tradeoffs or differences between these two ways to import and instantiate the EventEmitter class?

1: `var eventEmitter = new (require('events')).EventEmitter();`

2: `var eventEmitter = new (require('events').EventEmitter)();`

**My take:**

In 1, `(require('events'))` should return the exports of the `events` module. Then `.EventEmitter()` references that class and `new` create a new instance of `EventEmitter`.

In 2, `(require('events').EventEmitter) should return the exported EventEmitter class. Then`new...()`creates a new instance of`EventEmitter`.

Comment: Assuming you are using latest LTS of node or for that matter version after 0.12 - then you the '.EventEmitter' portion has been deprecated rather it is not needed. So you could just do: var evntEmitter = new (require('events'))();

Answer (score 1):

It is nothing unusual. You can put as many parentheses as you like around a function and then `()` after it and it will just work.

It's similar to

```
(1 + 2) === 3;
((1) + 2) === 3;
((1 + (2))) === (3);
```

etc... The same applies to objects/functions.

```
class MyClass { /* ... */ }

const object = {
    c: MyClass,
};
let a = new object.c();

console.log(a === new (object).c());
console.log(a === new ((object.c))());
console.log(a === new ((object).c)());
```

etc...

It's worth noticing what you cannot put parenthese after a dot `.`, so for example:

```
let a = new object.(c)();
```

would throw an error.